# Select id's containing all indicated Values (Wildcard collisions problem) MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, sql-like

The table in question (10.1.29-MariaDB):

```
  [Table] => blog_search
  [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `blog_search` (
  `bkey` varchar(28) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `blog_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `follows` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `bkey` (`bkey`,`blog_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `blog_id` (`blog_id`,`bkey`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `bkey_follows` (`bkey`,`follows`,`blog_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

`bkey` is a word used in the title of a blog. The `follows` data would be repeated per word per blog.

I had a Select that worked great without wildcards (key=>`bkey_follow` chosen by DB):

```
SELECT blog_id
FROM blog_search
WHERE bkey = 'news' OR bkey = 'usa'
GROUP BY blog_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY FOLLOWS DESC
LIMIT 30
```

But when I used wildcards (key=>`bkey` chosen by DB):

```
WHERE bkey LIKE 'news%' OR bkey LIKE 'usa%'
```

It still is able to do a index search, but '*news*' and  '*newsletter*' key words would match as COUNT(*) = 2, but it would not have found '*usa*'

I made this new query, that works like I wanted, but if the last word have lots of results, the query becomes much slower (since queries are executed from back to front, and has to read 100% of the index) (key=>`blog_id` chosen by DB):

```
SELECT blog_id
FROM blog_search
WHERE  
  blog_id IN (SELECT blog_id FROM blog_search WHERE bkey LIKE 'news%') 
  AND blog_id IN (SELECT blog_id FROM blog_search WHERE bkey LIKE 'usa%')
GROUP BY blog_id
ORDER BY follows DESC
LIMIT 30
```

If I `FORCE INDEX (bkey)` or even better `FORCE INDEX (bkey_follows)` it improves a little bit, like 35% but still is x10 times slower that I think should be possible.

I would like a query that's more optimized, without sub-queries. Something like this **WRONG** query, (but a correct version):

```
SELECT blog_id, 0 AS dist1, 0 AS dist2
FROM blog_search
WHERE ( bkey LIKE 'news%' AND 1=dist1=1 )
   OR ( bkey LIKE 'usa%' AND 1=dist2=1 )
GROUP BY blog_id
HAVING (dist1=1 AND dist2=1)
ORDER BY follows DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Additional data: I'm developing searches for titles of blogs/posts. I tried many things: Regex, LIKE %...%, and FULLTEXT index which I "approved" to use for relevancy ordered results. The more promising search is the one discussed in this question, because is the best for it's speed and at ordering results by 'follows'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't care how many rows match.  Many other solutions lead to the "explode-implode" syndrome.  That is where you gather lots of rows, only to later boil down to just a few via `GROUP BY`.  This avoids half of that by using a "semi-join", `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT blog_id
    FROM blog_search AS o
    WHERE WHERE bkey LIKE 'news%'
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT blog_id FROM blog_search
                      WHERE bkey LIKE 'usa%'
                        AND blog_id = o.blog_id )
ORDER BY follows DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Very fast, I will continue testing, this might be the one I use. There is a little mistake by the way `WHERE WHERE bkey LIKE 'news%')` I changed to `WHERE bkey LIKE 'news%'`

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase the `having` clause as:

```
SELECT blog_id
FROM blog_search
WHERE bkey LIKE 'news%' OR bkey = 'usa%'
GROUP BY blog_id
HAVING SUM( bkey LIKE 'news%' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( bkey LIKE 'usa%' ) > 0
ORDER BY FOLLOWS DESC
LIMIT 30
```

A convenient way to filter before the aggregation is to use regular expressions:

```
SELECT blog_id
FROM blog_search
WHERE bkey REGEXP 'news|use' 
GROUP BY blog_id
HAVING SUM( bkey LIKE 'news%' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( bkey LIKE 'usa%' ) > 0
ORDER BY FOLLOWS DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: `REGEXP` works OK for small tables.  But for large tables, the necessary table-scan will be a performance killer.  `OR` with `LIKE` suffers the same problem.

Comment: The `HAVING SUM()` solution looks like what I was trying to do, but I cannot make it work, gives me 0 results.  

Regarding REGEXP, I already tried a search with it and was the slowest since it does not use the index for comparing the REGEXP expression.

Comment: @Vixxs . . . Perhaps you have no blogs that match these conditions.

Comment: @gordon, I figured it out, `OR bkey = 'usa%'` to `OR bkey LIKE 'usa%'`, I didn't noticed it before.  

  It works now as expected, as fast as I thought it could get. (Rick answer is performing x2.2 faster for this particular test.)  
 
  I'm going to do more testing and see which one performs better overall with different searches. Thank you guys.

Comment: @Vixxs . . . You might also want to compare them with wildcards at the beginning of the `LIKE` patterns, instead of at the end.